Not possible to render using optix via bpy in docker image
Background: I'm currently trying to setup a server that accepts jobs and renders them in the background using blender. I have already found similar solutions, however, I wanted to build it from scratch. Within that webserver would like to be utilising the bpy python package only instead of spawning a new blender process for more control.
Problem:
Tldr:

rendering with CUDA works in docker container and on host (installation from website download)
rendering with Optix works on the host with installation from download, but not when compiled in the docker image
Compilation seems to be done with Optix and succeeds - preprocessor symbol WITH_OPTIX seems to be defined and Optix is outputted as a valid device type within bpy

long version:
I have come to the point that I can render simple scenes using cuda within that docker image. The following code runs fine using cuda (or cpu):
import bpy 
    
blend_file = '/usr/src/app/test.blend'
bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=blend_file)
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES' 

device_type = 'CUDA'
bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'
bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.compute_device_type = device_type
bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.refresh_devices()
bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.get_devices()

for device in bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.devices:
    print(device.type, device.name)
    if device.type  == device_type:
        device.use = True   
    else:
        device.use = False    
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True) 


However, no Optix capable device is being listed and changing device_type to 'OPTIX' does not work. However, the the following bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.get_device_types(None) 
returns that Optix is a supported device type.
When running the same code as stated above on my host with device_type='OPTIX' it is running just fine with Optix and bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.devices also lists my graphics card as an optix as well as cuda device.
I made sure that I built everything using coda and optix, primarily using the following flags:
cmake . -DPYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES=/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/  \
  -DWITH_PLAYER=OFF -DWITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON -DWITH_INSTALL_PORTABLE=OFF \
  -DWITH_CYCLES_CUDA_BINARIES=ON \
  -DWITH_CYCLES_DEVICE_CUDA=ON \
  -DWITH_CYCLES_DEVICE_OPTIX=ON \
  -DOPTIX_ROOT_DIR=/optix_8.0.0

/optix_8.0.0 is the root path when downloading optix from the nvidia homepage which contains the include, SDK and doc folder. Checking out the FindOptix.cmake this seems plausible. Moreover, I checked if I could find flags were passed along the line which seem to indicate that indeed all optix relevant files were included. I could find many instances of  -DWITH_OPTIX in flags.make files which seem to indicate that this worked. This symbol is e.g. being used in blender_build_source/intern/cycles/device/device.cpp -> available_types() which also explains why Optix seems to be recognised as a possible device type.
It seems to me that some initialization is going wrong e.g. missing some include dir at runtime. However, I have no idea on how to debug this e.g. more verbosity or specific python api that returns the status of optix initialization.
Does somebody have an idea of what might be going wrong here?
update:
I found by adding some print statements the function optixInitWithHandle that libnvoptix.so.1 cannot be found. apparently since some version this library is provided together with the nvidia driver https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/libnvoptix-so-1-not-installed-by-the-driver/221704. Now since im using the nvidia driver from the host this library is nowhere to be found for blender... . I copied the library over from the host -> now it finds it but breaks which im guessing is because of a missmatch of the headers im giving it to compile and the library it then tries to load.
more background:
graphics card: 4070 SUPER
host Os: linux
Nvidia driver on host: 550
cuda version: 12
the complete docker image -> not cleaned up sorry

ENV PYTHON_VERSION 3.11

RUN  apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \ 
    git \
    git-lfs \
    subversion \
    build-essential \ 
    cmake \
    libx11-dev \
    libxxf86vm-dev \
    libxcursor-dev \
    libxi-dev \
    libxrandr-dev \
    libxinerama-dev \
    libegl-dev \
    libwayland-dev \
    wayland-protocols  \
    libxkbcommon-dev \
    libdbus-1-dev \
    linux-libc-dev && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN  apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \ 
    ca-certificates \                             
    && update-ca-certificates && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN  apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
     add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
     apt-get install -y python$PYTHON_VERSION \
     python3-pip && \
     apt-get clean && \
     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN  apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nvidia-cuda-toolkit 

RUN mkdir blender_dir && cd blender_dir && git clone https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender.git --single-branch --depth 1 
RUN cd blender_dir/blender/ && ./build_files/utils/make_update.py --use-linux-libraries
RUN cd blender_dir/blender && make update && make bpy CC=/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin/gcc CPP=/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin/g++ CXX=/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin/g++ LD=/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin/g++
    
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget 
COPY NVIDIA-OptiX-SDK-8.0.0-linux64-x86_64 /optix_8.0.0
    
RUN ln -fs /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++ && \
    ln -fs /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc && \
    mkdir /optix_8.0.0/SDK/build && cd  /optix_8.0.0/SDK/build && \
     cmake .. && make -j$(nproc)

RUN cd blender_dir/build_linux_bpy && cmake . -DPYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES=/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/  \
  -DWITH_PLAYER=OFF -DWITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON -DWITH_INSTALL_PORTABLE=OFF \
  -DWITH_CYCLES_CUDA_BINARIES=ON \
  -DWITH_CYCLES_DEVICE_CUDA=ON \
  -DWITH_CYCLES_DEVICE_OPTIX=ON \
  -DOPTIX_ROOT_DIR=/optix_8.0.0/ \ && make install -j$(nproc)

    

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends doxygen libopenexr-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglfw3-dev libxinerama-dev libxcursor-dev && apt-get clean 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends dkms libglfw3-dev pkg-config libglvnd-dev && apt-get clean 

RUN cp -r /blender_dir/blender/lib/linux_x64/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/* /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsm6
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY blender_render.py /usr/src/app
COPY test.blend /usr/src/app



So basically the main question is about building Blender. Blender development questions are generally considered off-topic here. I will not vote to close as off-topic, but it's probably unlikely you will get help with this here. Maybe ask for help on devtalk forums.

You also did not mention anything about what happens if you compile on host. I would probably start there then.

thanks for the comment and sorry for misplacing this topic. Since it seems like im able to solve it,I might as well leave it and update it, maybe someone else has the same issue and might help that person.
I did not build it on the host on purpose, I just installed it from package. since it is the same OS I thought it should work with Nvidia drivers and display manager being the biggest risks - I would not have gained much knowledge in my opinion. Rather me messing up my system e.g. by sym linking gcc ;)

Please note that this is not a regular form. It's a question and answer site. If you find an answer, you should post it as an answer, not an update or edit. There should be a clear question and a clear answer.

okay get it, thanks!

I found the solution to the problem. I was missing the shared libraries libnvoptix as well as the rtcore library. Once I copied those over it works. Note that copying over is probably not the right way to do it since they are shipped with the driver and thus probably will fail once a new driver is installed. Here is the post that helped me https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/libnvoptix-so-1-not-installed-by-the-driver/221704/8
